# Using PlistBuddy and grep to dump dictionary values

Tags: bash, terminal

Hello guys, I've been trying to get/dump data from a property list (.plist) file using PlistBuddy but I didn't find any proper way to do it. Here is a photo of my plist file:
[image]

For example, I'd like to get all Adult's names and ages in "[age] [name]" format, like: "Mark 31", each in one line. Is this anyhow doable in bash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at `plutil`. It can read a plist and output json which can then be parsed with jq:

```
plutil -convert json -o - people.plist | \
jq --raw-output '.People.Adults | .[] | "\(.name) \(.age)"'
Mark 31
James 34
John 24
```